# mySQL - How can I integrate this "last 3 days only" query

Tags: php, mysql

There are referer records in my database. All records include date,clicks, scrolls, countries etc.
And in here, I successfully group referer records and include average values of clicks, scrolls, countries etc. However, I also want to enable date range, like last 3 days.

[image]

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*), COUNT(conv), AVG(clicks), AVG(scrolls), 
AVG(spent) FROM track where referid='".$memberr."' GROUP BY 
referer ORDER BY ".$sortby." desc limit 0,35
```

How can I integrate this last 3 days query with my mysql_query above ?

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y-%m-%d') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi)

Comment: You're using `GROUP BY` incorrectly.

Comment: The `SELECT *, ...` should be `SELECT referer, ...` since you have a `GROUP BY referer`. Otherwise, you may get erroneous results, as @FreshPrinceOfSO points.

Comment: @user198989 in the example you show a time value, reference to `UNIXTIME` and are seeming to track data that requires precision to the minute or maybe even second.  But you also mention `date` as a keyword.  My gut tells me you need precision -- please consider what you need and let us know what precision you require on your calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple thing to do, you just need to add another condition:

```
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND date <= CURDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a difference with your date condition query and mine ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that using DATE_SUB will be faster than plain subtraction (this function was written for a reason) ;). Also you need to put the subtraction in your code into brackets.

Comment: just a note that if you are working with timestamps then `curdate()` is going to give you potentially not the right answer.  For example if it was 2359h today (May 3rd)and you used `date_sub(curdate(), interval 3 day)` then you would be getting results from April 30th.  That is more like 4 days.  The same search run at 001h would contain data from a range that is  more than 23 hours shorter.

So if you want 3 days precisely then use `now()` instead.  Because of the data you are collecting using timestamps and `now()` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @gillyspy that is correct, and with that you should move away from time-stamps to date as a fix (which will give you proper control over it), not hack around it by using now().

Comment: @Puciek. Please Explain how `now()` is a "hack"? I am stating my assumptions, but your conjecture does not state the assumptions.

To explain further, based on clues in the question like multiple timezones and the clock having minute precision and no demonstration of date anywhere on the graphic I think this user actually wants to use timestamps.  Meaning they will want to use `now()`.

Comment: @gillyspy now() itself is not a hack, but using it in that context is. If you want to store date - then you should store date as with that it will be accurate, easy to manipulate and so on. Given that he wants to select by it - date seems to be in place, not a time-stamp (you are doing an unnecessary conversion). Especially since date will handle time zones better than just timestamp :). 
Anyway comments are not for prolonged debates, so if you wish to continue with it - feel free to chat me.

Comment: @Puciek you're assuming that the datatype is `date`, but not stating your assumption.  All we know is there is something called "date" whcih could be a column name with datatype timestamp.  You're also assuming that `date` datatype is desirable when no data type is given.  The reference to `UNIXTIME` is yet another reason to believe that precision is required and desired.

Comment: @gillyspy you can have the same precision with mysql date, it's called a datetime which holds the same level of precision as unix timestamp.

Comment: @Puciek The point is when you say curdate() you don't have that precision.